# Should I return null or -1 when searching for the id of a translation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

We are adding kotlin to our big project and many interesting discussions are appearing. We are having a hard one here when getting a translation for an enum element in a Utils class made in kotlin.

Since some enums have no translation I have decided to return null. 
Two of my colleagues say I should not do this. 
The arguments are that by convention (List.indexOf was mentioned) we return -1 when numeric elements are the return type.

I argue that the client has to check if the return is valid so this is not any clearer (and I think slightly worst). 
I was told my pull request won't be accepted until I find an example where in JDK or Android SDK the code returns null when some Int was not found.

I have read many questions in SO and although many people agree that empty containers and null are most recomended return values when something is not found, I have trouble getting an authorized party stating that null is correct here.

Please tell me if code is needed to understand better.

Comment: Does method return primitive or object? If primitive - you can't return null, if Object you **should** return null.

Comment: @user1055395 Kotlin force null check on nullable type. I think return null is the best solution.

Comment: Would `Map<Integer, Integer>` be the desired example?

Comment: @deathangel908 I made it return Int? they want me to return int (or read it as such in client)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov is the best I have, though may not fly well for my colleagues. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin as a language tries to avoid null as much as possible(compared to Java)

In this case, I would stick to -1 instead of using null like the example you gave :

```
list.IndexOf
```

Comment: Kotlin doens't try to avoid `null`, it just tries to limit NPEs by adding compile-time checks on nullable types

Comment: that is the part I am not sure of, but it seems to me is not trying to avoid its use entirely. I am trying to beat the argument null is always bad, kotlin seems to think is a valid value sometimes

Comment: As well as null is bad, `-1` can be misinterpreted in many cases at all, that could lead to bugs that are hard to find. `list.IndexOf` returns `int` primitive,  that's why it's `-1`.